# Fetch Users With Active Status on WIndows System

Tags: c#, windows

How can I fetch the list of users who are active and disconnected on the Windows Server System (similar to the list shown in Users' tab of Task Manager) using C#?

So far I could only fetch the list of all users on the system like as follows:

```
using System.Management;

SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Win32_UserAccount");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
foreach (ManagementObject envVar in searcher.Get())
{
     Console.WriteLine("Username : {0}", envVar["Name"]);
}
```

But I need the list of users who are currently active and disconnected.

Comment: You may be looking for [`WTSENumerateSessionsEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee621014(v=vs.85).aspx). No managed equivalent so far as I'm aware.

Comment: Thank you, Damien_The_Unbeliever. I would look into that.

Comment: @CodeJoger - Have you found a way to differentiate between active and disconnected users ?